# Purchase Paris Visite pass from Orly airport on a public holiday

Tags: public-transport, paris

Can I buy a Paris Visite pass (zone 1-5, days 1-3) from Orly airport on 8th May 2014? It is a public holiday in France.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ticket office at major stations such as the airport will be open even on a holiday. In addition, there are ticket machines that accept credit cards (all of them, since this is an RATP station — on the other hand, SNCF stations such as in Roissy airport have machines that only accept credit cards with chips), and I think the ones in the airport also take banknotes (most of the ones in the city don't).

You can even [buy tickets in advance from online resellers](http://www.ratp.fr/fr/ratp/r_91808/acheter-vos-titres-en-ligne/). I have no idea about extra costs and delivery times. But I'd just buy the ticket(s) at the airport.

Do check whether Paris Visite is really worth it. For many people, it isn't a good deal, but you need to match the price with what you're doing, and having a pass has the advantage that you don't need to think about cost before hopping onto a train or bus. [Paris Visite](http://www.ratp.fr/en/ratp/r_61654/parisvisite/) zones 1–5 (covering the city, both airports and the Versailles Palace) is 48.65€. An [Orlybus](http://www.ratp.fr/en/ratp/r_61866/orlybus/) ticket (I recommend the bus to Denfert-Rochereau over Orlyval, it's simpler and slightly cheaper) is 7.50€ one way. A ticket to Versailles is 3.45€ one way. A book of 10 tickets for travel in the city is 13.70€. 10 trips for 3 days without counting the Versailles and airport runs is a reasonable estimate, which makes Paris Visite worth buying only if you get 13.05€ worth of reductions from Paris Visite, which is doubtful.

Comment: Thanks alot for the prompt reply. As u said that RATP offices are opened also on holidays so i will buy the Paris Visite Pass from the ORLY Airport. 
I also read about the Card Machines but some one said that Paris Visite Pass can't be purchased with the machines.
Paris Visite Pass will hopefully worth me, as i have to go to CDG Airport, ORLY airport and Disneyland as well. SO as i have calculated it is a good option for me.
Thanks once again :)

Comment: @rafeymaher Oh, I think you're right: Paris Visite isn't just a ticket, there's also a leaflet and I think coupons for the attractions, so the machines can't hand it out. If you're going to CDG and Disneyland then indeed Paris Visite is a better deal for you than for the average tourist. Though perhaps [Mobilis](http://www.ratp.fr/fr/ratp/c_21148/mobilis/) (day pass) would come out cheaper (not advertised to tourists, I think it's only mentioned on the French part of the website) — then again probably not because Mobilis isn't valid for the airport trips.